# prevent builtwith.com showing what my site is built with

Tags: php, security, builtwith

Is there a way to mask my real server technology say from PHP to show up as Python when checked by sites like http://builtwith.com? Or at least to not show anything at all?

Comment: Since this is tagged `security` I have to point out that "masking" this information will not in any significant way increase security!

Comment: you want to hide .php extension for hide that you have devloped site in php ?

Comment: URL?  Google doesn't know of any site named "buildwith".

Comment: Not sure then why but here is the site builtwith.com works fine I just seemed to have misspelled it

Comment: http://builtwith.com/removals.aspx would hide everything!

Comment: The removals url has changed: http://builtwith.com/removals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using apache, you can change the default "tell all" behaviour with the [ServerTokens](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servertokens) and [ServerSignature](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serversignature) directives:

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
```

This'll remove identifying marks from error pages, and only return the server name with HTTP requests, instead of all of your installed modules.  Here's an example with `ServerTokens` commented out:

```
14:45:52 bartley:~ > curl -I http://www.test.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 16 May 2011 13:54:48 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (EL) DAV/2 PHP/5.2.16 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.8.8
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 16457
Cache-Control: max-age=300, must-revalidate
Expires: Mon, 16 May 2011 13:59:48 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

..and here's one with it set to `Prod`:

```
14:44:25 bartley:~ > curl -I http://www.test.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 16 May 2011 13:54:19 GMT
Server: Apache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 16457
Cache-Control: max-age=300, must-revalidate
Expires: Mon, 16 May 2011 13:59:19 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

**EDIT:** As @Marc points out, there is also a HTTP header that PHP can add an `X-Powered-By` header to.  This can be disabled by adding `expose_php = Off` in your `php.ini`.

Comment: There is the `X-Powered-By` header, which is controlled by `expose_php` in php.ini. Apache's configuration is NOT the only place that PHP can expose itself.

Answer (score 4):

The link provided by builtwith.com to remove your site from their lookup service is:

http://builtwith.com/removals

(Credit due to the person with user name "[gary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57325/gary)" who originally posted this link as [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018270/prevent-builtwith-com-showing-what-my-site-is-built-with#comment6965211_6018270) on the question; however, the link has since changed and it is better posted in an answer so it can be easily seen.)

Comment: Keep in mind that removing this info from one site (like builtwith) still leaves a lot of other sites scraping the same information. So the best option is to prevent this data from being leaked at the server level.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this question asked with many other packages, the result is always that hiding what something is running, that's publicly accessible, is not really possible, and not worth the time - time's better spent tightening real security issues like keeping private directories private etc, correct set-up and keeping the software up to date

Answer (score 1):

If you are using LiteSpeed, you can set the `Server` and `X-Powered-By` headers to anything you like, using either `.htaccess` or PHP.

**.htaccess**

```
Header always set X-Powered-By Something
Header always set Server Something
```

**PHP**

```php
header('X-Powered-By: Something');
header('Server: Something');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think they test some path those are unique path for CMSs and index your website info in their databases. I try to use "IP Deny Manager" in Cpanel to denny IP of those domains in order to prevents from unwanted indexing by those sites.