# Could it be possible that we can hide from Builtwith and other search engines the make of WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, web, hidden

I am working on the WordPress site but I don't want the search engines as well as BuiltWith can detect that the site is built in the WordPress, can someone please help me how it could be possible.

Comment: why do u want to do that??

Comment: that is the requirement from one of client I am working with, I did research but not able to find any relevant info regarding the same

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look here:

(1) http://codecanyon.net/item/hide-my-wp-no-one-can-know-you-use-wordpress/4177158/comments?page=14 The Plugin they're discussing about is Hide My WP

(2) http://www.graemeboy.com/how-to-hide-that-you-use-wordpress

(3) [prevent builtwith.com showing what my site is built with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018270/prevent-builtwith-com-showing-what-my-site-is-built-with)

(4) https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32023/how-to-hide-from-builtwith

Comment: i don't want the search engines as well as google can detect that the site is built in the WordPress